# Reverse truth table to generate boolean statement?

Tags: algorithm

So I'm given some scenarios where I exhaustively generate a list of possible events:

```
A = True, B = True, C = True -> True
A = False, B = False, C = True -> True
... more lists ...
```

any suggestions on merging them, to something like

```
( A || B || C )
```

thanks

Comment: Have a google for _Karnaugh map_.

Comment: so StackOverflow is also good for homework?

Comment: thanks, because this never comes up when it's not homework.

Comment: Do you want to minimise or otherwise optimise the generated expression, or would any expressions that gives the right answer do?

Comment: Not necessarily minimise, but optimize a bit for display.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [k-map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

Answer (score 1):

Karnaugh-Map is a table in which the row and columns are ordered not in a binary order but in a gray code order. Most likely by solving the k-map you can eliminate short-circuit and non-maskable interrupts.