# Find a boolean expression from a truth table (several bits)

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, truthtable, karnaugh-map

I have the following truth table (a and b being my inputs and r the result):

| a | b | r |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00 | 00 | 00 |
| 00 | 01 | 01 |
| 00 | 11 | 01 |
| 01 | 00 | 01 |
| 01 | 01 | 01 |
| 01 | 11 | 01 |
| 11 | 00 | 01 |
| 11 | 01 | 01 |
| 11 | 11 | 11 |

The issue is that I can't find the boolean expression to express this truth table.
Another [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316136/reverse-truth-table-to-generate-boolean-statement) pointed out that [karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) could solve it, but I can't find any implementation working with several bits inputs.

---

Note that to my model, the second bit doesn't matter is the first one is set for a specific input, thus if it facilitates the boolean expression, I can force it to 0, to 1, or not even force it.

Answer (score 0):

Truth Table (given):

```
a0 a1 b0 b1  r0 r1
0  0  0  0   0  0
0  0  0  1   0  1
0  0  1  1   0  1
0  1  0  0   0  1
0  1  0  1   0  1
0  1  1  1   0  1
1  1  0  0   0  1
1  1  0  1   0  1
1  1  1  1   1  1
```

Kmaps:

```
r0:
    \a0a1
b0b1 \ | 00| 01  11  10
00     | 0 | 1   1   1
        ---
01       1   1   1   1

11       1   1   1   1
        ---
10     | x | x   x   x
       |   |


r1:
    \a0a1
b0b1 \   00  01  11  10
00       0   0   0   0

01       0   0   0   0
                ---  
11       0   0 | 1 | 0
               |   |
10       x   x | x | x
                ---
```

Boolean Expressions:

```
r0 = a0 + a1 + b1

r1 = a0a1b0
```